# Animation Error: _animation_update_transforms: Failed setting key

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

I'm getting an error as such:

> E 0:00:00.744   _animation_update_transforms:   Failed setting key at
> time 0 in Animation 'Running' at Node '/path/to/AnimationPlayer',
> Track 'path/to/custom node:rotation_degrees'.
>
> Check if property exists or the type of key is right for the property
> <C++ Source>  scene/animation/animation_player.cpp:871 @
> _animation_update_transforms()

I'm trying to rotate a custom node (made by extending `position2D`) in animation but for some reason this error shows up.

According to the error:

> Check if property exists

since I've extended `position2D` the rotation property exists

and the other part:

> type of key is right for the property

I believe the values for the key are accurate, as when I hover over the keys
all the values seem to be accurate:

[image]

How do I fix this error?
or anyway to further isolate the error to pinpoint exactly where it's occurring within my custom node script?

Comment: Just a few more questions:
* when do you start the animation?
* did you try other rotation_degrees values to make sure its generally not possible to set the value?

Comment: @RenéKling the animation starts at 0:0 auto-starts on playing instance. I didn't set the `rotation_degrees` via code, I pressed 'E' and rotated it manually by mouse

Comment: My only guess is that the node path is pointing to the wrong node, one that does not have the property.

Comment: If you find the time, could you upload the node causing the problem somewhere? Then I could take a look at it. If possible strip anything not related to the problem.

Comment: @RenéKling I actually bypassed this approach completely since it was unpredictable but if I ever return to it I'll surely upload a sample project

Answer (score 0):

if you are editing animation with godot script. You should update points that are set by auto.

Try something like this:

$AnimationPlayer.get_animation("rotate").value_track_set_update_mode(0, Animation.UPDATE_CAPTURE)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck "Reset on Save" option on the AnimationPlayer Node and delete "RESET" animation.